# Auto Redirect When User Is Taking Too Long Input In Activity Android

Tags: android, timer, runtime, handler

I have a scenario, which when a User Rating, or inputting on a data, then the current Activity will Time it to the setted time.
So, if the User isn't do Anything, or taking the Action to Long, then the current Activity will direct the User into the MainActivity.

In my case, i have a Rating app, which is located in a Public place. I thought that if People wants to Rate BUT not completing the Quiz phase, then i don't want to leave the last Quiz to meet the new People who wants to Rate.

I've tried using these code:

```
int timeout = 4000;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent homepage = new Intent(Quiz2.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(homepage);
                finish();
            }
        }, timeout);
```

And these one:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(Quiz2.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        }, 4000);
```

It works, but it didn't work as expected, as it apply to ALL of the activities (I mean, after these code works in Current Activity, the Rest of the Activities is Applied and Timed too)

I don't want this. What i want is to Apply these Timer ONLY in Current Activity.
How this can be done?

Appreciate for any help, Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand what you actually wanna do,
but I'm guessing using CountDownTimer and then starting the other activity when the timer finished should do the trick.

```
new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     // You could show the user the time left using `millisUntilFinished`
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     // Do something when the timer is finished (start your activity & finish)
 }
}.start();
```

Comment: I mean with my question above is, when i applied that code in `SecondActivity.java`, then the `Thirdctivity.java`, `FourthActivity.java`, and the rest `Activity` will be applied too as the Timer code i applied in the `SecondActivity.java`.

What i want is when i apply the timer, then it will be applied only to `SecondActivity.java` not the rest of `Activity`.

Thank you for the answer, it'll mark it done if it work